# Check Constraints on Decimals In SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, check-constraints

I have the following check constraint on an NVARCHAR(255) column:

`([weekReviewWk10]='A' OR [weekReviewWk10]>=(0) AND [weekReviewWk10]<=(25))`

However, when someone enters, say, 23.5, SQL Server rejects the input. How can I fix this? I know it is because it is testing things as `ints`, but how do I get it to test the entry as a decimal?

The column has to be NVARCHAR since, as you can see, I also need my users to be able to enter 'A'.

Comment: How to fix it? Proper database design :-)

Comment: "*The column **has to be** NVARCHAR since, as you can see, I also need my users to be able to enter 'A'.*" Really? And you don't mind that they can also enter `'23.5.76'` or ``'23.5.7A,bc'`` or `'2A.5B.C76'`. i.e. nonsense data?

Comment: These are the business processes we have - I can't change them. We have a frontend in Access where teachers enter marks for tasks and they use 'A' to indicate absence. They enter the date through a datasheet. I could try and point the datasheet to update two different tables depending on it being numeric or char, but that would be difficult in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TRY_CAST to cast the column to a decimal format before comparing.

```
weekReviewWk10='A' OR
TRY_CAST(weekReviewWk10 AS decimal(3, 1)) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 25.0
```

If the cast fails, the result of TRY_CAST will be NULL and the comparison is false, but it won't crash. TRY_CAST requires SQL Server 2012 or newer.

It's worth mentioning that you're potentially opening up a pit of bad things when you allow text values in a numeric column, but judging from the question, you already know that. :)

Comment: They have numeric values in a text column, which is equally bad of course ;)

Comment: It says "can't validate check constraint".

Comment: @fluffybonkers sorry, had the wrong column name. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I know. I saw that and changed the column name myself, however, I get the same error.

Comment: It seems to be because I had square brackets around the field names...

Comment: Though now it lets me introduce the constraint, it still won't let me enter decimals. I am working on a trigger that will put the 'A' values in another table at this point. It is 24.5 specifically - I presume SQL Server does some weird rounding.